# Handling Query string in sequelize when you are not sure whether query string exists

Tags: sequelize.js

please I want to query an address table using request query parameters..
I want to query based on County, State and City.
Such that

```
     Adressses.findall({
        where:
          {
           country: req.query.country, 
           state: req.query.state,
           city: req.query.city  //what if user didnot select city?
         }
```

The issue this, I am not sure of which query parameter, the user would select.
What if undefined is passed?
How can i avoid a null or undefined as value for the attributes.
Or can i do anything like:

```
Adressses.findall({
  where:
        {
         country: req.query.country || "value that selects all", 
         state: req.query.state,   || "or a fallback value",
         city: req.query.city     || "safe value",
       }
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)  is the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it before sending as filter. For example

```
let filter={};
filter.test= req.query.test;
filter.id = req.query.id;
```

As test here is the url and filter

```
localhost:3000/api/user?id=1

{
    "id": "1"
}

localhost:3000/api/user?id=1&test=test
{
    "test": "test",
    "id": "1"
}
```

Then your query will be

```
 Adressses.findall({
        where: filter
})
```